# Python and JSON - if Key matches Move value from a key to root key

Tags: python, json

I have an application which generates clickstream data and pushes the data into a JSON. Almost 1000 clicks data will be saved in that file.

### File contents:  (steam-00001.json)

```
{
    "date": {
        "s": "2019-04-20"
    },
    "name": {
        "s": "www.mywebsite.com"
    },
    "products": {
        "m": {
            "13128": {
                "m": {
                    "quantity": {
                        "s": "1"
                    },
                    "price": {
                        "n": "799"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} 
{
    "date": {
        "s": "2019-04-20"
    },
    "name": {
        "s": "www.mywebsite.com"
    },
    "products": {
        "m": {
            "13128": {
                "m": {
                    "quantity": {
                        "s": "1"
                    },
                    "price": {
                        "n": "799"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you see the above JSON file, all of my values are pointed with s,m,n. The developers used this for some reference.

- S - Single value
- M - Multiple value
- N - Number

Now I need to **remove these references**. I tried multiple `json load` and `dumps` but not able to achieve what im expecting. 
Could someone help me on this?

### Expected Output:

```
{
    "date": "2019-04-20",
    "name": "www.mywebsite.com",
    "products": {
        "13128": {
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "799"
        }
    }
}
{
    "date": "2019-04-20",
    "name": "www.mywebsite.com",
    "products": {
        "13128": {
            "quantity": "1",
            "price": "799"
        }
    }
}
```

### Steps I tried:

```py
import json
def load_json_multiple(segments):
    chunk = ""
    for segment in segments:
        chunk += segment
        try:
            yield json.loads(chunk)
            chunk = ""
        except ValueError:
            pass
def filterJson(payload):
    for key, value in payload.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            for key1 in value.keys():
                if(key1 == "M"):
                    payload[key] = value["M"]
            tmp = filterJson(value)
            if(tmp != None):
                payload[key] = tmp
                #print ans
        else:
            if(key == "S" or key == "N"):
                return payload.pop(key)
with open('/home/ec2-user/olddata', 'r') as f:
    for parsed_json in load_json_multiple(f):
        print parsed_json
        filterJson(parsed_json)
        print parsed_json
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi question updated with the details